# Javascript function declaration conversion

Tags: javascript, function, type-conversion, declaration

I have a JavaScript function declared as

```
myFunction: function() {

// some codes...

}
```

and I want to convert the declaration format to

```
function myFunction() {

// some codes...

}
```

First of all what is the difference between these two and how can I convert vice versa?

Comment: The first is "declared" as object property, the second is a normal function declaration. How do you plan to *convert* one to another?

Comment: I want to convert first format to second one. So that my code should work in second format too.

Comment: You're clearly missing something. Those declarations are two different things for two different purposes. There is no advantage in choosing one over the other. In fact you cannot choose at all. It all depends on WHERE you want to declare your function. So what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: I want to make the first format function to work without object property.

Comment: Or simply, can I merge these two formats?

Comment: Could you give us a real life code example?

Answer (score 0):

First one is creating a function within an object, the second one is a standard function declaration.

Your options are:

```
var myFunction = function() {};
```

and

```
function myFunction() {};
```

and

```
var myObject = {
    myFunction:function() {};
}
```

The only way to use the first function the way the second function is used, is by getting it out of the object it's declared in.

Comment: Please explain little more about how _getting it out of the object it's declared in._